# Error : cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to' char' in assignment

Tags: c++, dev-c++, visual-c++

> Error : cannot convert '' to' char' in assignment

no sé porque se produce ni como solucionarlo el error me produce aquí

```
void nombreequipos(char *equipos[12],int equipocasa, int equipovisita)
{
    cout<<"-------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"-- LISTADO DE EQUIPOS DE PRIMERA DIVISION / CR --"<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    
   *equipos[12]=
    {
        "[1] - Alajuelense",
        "[2] - CS Herediano",
        "[3] - Guadalupe",
        "[4] - Perez zeledon",
        "[5] - Santos Guapiles",
        "[6] - AD Grecia",
        "[7] - Deportivo Saprissa",
        "[8] - CS Cartagines",
        "[9] - San Carlos",
        "[10] - Limon",
        "[11] - Jicaral Sercoba",
        "[12] - Sporting San Jose"
    }; // aqui me lo marca como error
```

pero lo que no entiendo es porque se produce si estoy inicializando el vector con sus valores correctamente, entonces nose porque me dice que el vector no esta inicializado correctamente

Comment: Esa sintaxis solo es valida si lo incializas donde lo declaras.

Comment: pero yo la declare por ejemplo en esa funcion desde el prototipo de la funcion y basicamente la estoy inicializando desde aqui pero entonces que deberia hacer para solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Empecemos por traducir el error:

> ```
> cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to' char' in assignment
> ```

> ```
> no se puede convertir '<lista entre llaves>' a' char' en asignación
> ```

Ahora ¿Dónde en tu código estás **asignando** una **lista entre llaves**? Pues aquí:

```
//          v <--- Asignación
*equipos[12]=
 {                               //   \
     "[1] - Alajuelense",        //   |
     "[2] - CS Herediano",       //   |
     "[3] - Guadalupe",          //   |
     "[4] - Perez zeledon",      //   |
     "[5] - Santos Guapiles",    //   |
     "[6] - AD Grecia",          //    > ---- Lista entre llaves
     "[7] - Deportivo Saprissa", //   |
     "[8] - CS Cartagines",      //   |
     "[9] - San Carlos",         //   |
     "[10] - Limon",             //   |
     "[11] - Jicaral Sercoba",   //   |
     "[12] - Sporting San Jose"  //   |
 };                              //   /
```

El error indica que estás intentando asignar a `' char'`, eso es porque `equipos` es una formación<sup>1</sup> de doce punteros a carácter (`char`), la instrucción `*equipos[12]` se interpreta de la siguiente manera: `*(equipos[12])` que significa lo siguiente: *Dame el puntero que está en la treceava posición (índice doce) y accede a su contenido (que es un `char`)*:

```
//        Contenido de esto
//   _____^______
//  /            \
    *(equipos[12])
//           \__/
//             \___ Treceava posición
```

En resumen, `*equipos[12]` es un carácter al que le intentas asignar una lista, cosa que no es posible y de ahí el error.

> estoy inicializando el vector con sus valores correctamente

No lo haces. Esa instrucción no es una inicialización si no una **asignación**. A una formación<sup>1</sup> no se pueden **asignar** valores, la manera de dotarla de datos es mediante una inicialización (no **asignación**) o copiando datos a su espacio de memoria.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: bastante detallada tu respuesta @PaperBirdMaster pense que nadie me responderia ya, pero gracias por tu respuesta, pero entonces tu dices que *equipos[12] es un caracter al que intento asignar una lista, pero yo antes de hacer programas lo que ago es que planteo toda la logica en un programa corrido en la funcion main luego lo voy separando entre las funciones, pero entonces tu me dices que no puedo, pero en mi otro codigo yo lo tengo igual a como te lo mostre y el codigo funciona bien, entonces porque dentro de una funcion sucede este error y no en la funcion main donde lo tenia y funcionaba